# React Native change container height pixel parameters to flex values and display list as two columns

Tags: reactjs, react-native, flexbox

With the map function i create a radio list with 10 radio buttons. I need to display this list in two columns. The only way i managed to get it work is by setting my container height to 200 pixels and flexWrap:"wrap" so i got 5 list items per column .How could i achieve the same effect only using flex dimensions and not setting height:200 ? To my understanding my styles.flexContainer is parent and i have to set it to flex:1, i am changing flex value to styles.container from 1 to even 15 and i dont see any changes to the containers height. **I need the style.container View to be 1/2 size of the parent flexContainer**

```
export function RadioGrid({ label, options, onChange, value }: RadioGridProps) {
    return (
            <View style={styles.flexContainer}>
            <View style={styles.container}>
                {options.map((option) => (
                    <Radio
                        style={styles.radio}
                        checked={option.value === value}
                        key={option.value}
                        label={option.label}
                        onPress={() => onChange(option.value)}
                    />
                ))}
            </View>
           </View>
    );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    radio: {
        paddingVertical: 8,
        marginRight: 40,
    },
    container: {
        flex:2,
        //height: 200,
        flexWrap: "wrap",
    },
    flexContainer: {
        flex: 1,
    },
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an easy way to achieve what you want. You could use a `FlatList` with `numColumn` being equal to two.

```js
export function RadioGrid({ label, options, onChange, value }: RadioGridProps) {
  return (
    <View style={styles.flexContainer}>
      <FlatList
        data={options}
        keyExtractor={(item) => item.value}
        numColumns={2}
        renderItem={({ item }) => {
          return (
            <Radio
              style={styles.radio}
              checked={item.value === value}
              key={item.value}
              label={item.label}
              onPress={() => onChange(item.value)}
            />
          );
        }}
      />
    </View>
  );
}
```

The FlatList component will manage everything for you.

If you still want to use `map`, then this could be implemented as follows.

First, convert your `options` array to an array of pairs.

```js
const pairs = options.reduce(
  (result, _, index, array) =>
    index % 2 === 0 ? [...result, array.slice(index, index + 2)] : result,
   []
);
```

Then, map over `pairs` and create a new `View` for each pair with `flexDirection: 'row'` and add a `Radio` for each element of the pairs.

```js
return (
    <View style={styles.flexContainer}>
      {pairs.map((pair) => {
        return (
          <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }}>
            {pair.map((element) => (
              <Radio
                style={styles.radio}
                checked={element.value === value}
                key={element.value}
                label={element.label}
                onPress={() => onChange(element.value)}
              />
            ))}
          </View>
        );
      })}
    </View>
  );
```

The complete code:

```js
export function RadioGrid({ label, options, onChange, value }: RadioGridProps) {
  const pairs = options.reduce(
    (result, _, index, array) =>
      index % 2 === 0 ? [...result, array.slice(index, index + 2)] : result,
    []
  );
  return (
    <View style={styles.flexContainer}>
      {pairs.map((pair) => {
        return (
          <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }}>
            {pair.map((element) => (
              <Radio
                style={styles.radio}
                checked={element.value === value}
                key={element.value}
                label={element.label}
                onPress={() => onChange(element.value)}
              />
            ))}
          </View>
        );
      })}
    </View>
  );
}
```

Comment: thank you for the very detailed reply! Everything is showing fine using the FlatList except i got an error in the console : VirtualizedLists should never be nested inside plain ScrollViews with the same orientation....

Comment: Are you nesting `RadioGrid` inside a `ScrollView`?

Comment: yes i have the main app file with different components including RadioGrid nested in a ScrollView

Comment: ok, you shouldn't nest two scrollviews (or in this case a FlatList inside a ScrollView). The quickest fix would be to use the second solution using map that I have provided above.